# More efficient way to Iterate & compute over columns

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a very wide dataframe > 10,000 columns and I need to compute the percent of nulls in each. Right now I am doing:

```
threshold=0.9
for c in df_a.columns[:]:
    if df_a[df_a[c].isNull()].count() >= (df_a.count()*threshold):
        # print(c)
        df_a=df_a.drop(c)
```

Of course this is a slow process and crashes on occasion. Is there a more efficient method I am missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are few strategies you can take depending upon the size of the dataframe. The code looks good to me. You need to go through each column and count the number of null values.

One strategy is to cache the input dataframe. That will enable faster filtering. This however works if the dataframe is not huge

Also

```
df_a=df_a.drop(c)
```

I am little skeptical with this as this is changing the dataframe in the loop. Better to keep the null column names and drop from the dataframe later in a separate loop.

If the dataframe is huge and you can't cache it completely you can partition the dataframe in to some finite manageable columns. Like take 100 column each and cache that smaller dataframe and run the analysis 100 times in a loop.

Now you might want to keep track of the analyzed column list separate from the yet to be analyzed columns in this case. That way even if the job fails you can start the analysis from the rest of the columns.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid iterating when using pyspark, since it does not distribute the computations anymore.
Using `count` on a column will compute the `count` of non-null elements.

```py
threshold = 0.9
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
count_df = df_a\
    .agg(*[psf.count("*").alias("count")]+ [psf.count(c).alias(c) for c in df_a.columns])\
    .toPandas().transpose()
```

The first element is the number of lines in the dataframe:

```py
total_count = count_df.iloc[0, 0]
kept_cols = count_df[count_df[0] > (1 - threshold)*total_count].iloc[1:,:]
df_a.select(list(kept_cols.index))
```